# How to connect device to DJANGO local server?

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

**I have a local server written in python-django(restapi) and an android app (using retrofitclient). What I want to do is the login part without using the emulator. With the emulator using the ip `10.0.2.2`, worked.  I am connected with the mobile in the same network as my laptop, more than that I shared the connection from pc in order to not have restrictions. At the server side I set `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'**]`.

My ip-adress is `192.168.56.1` the port on which I run the server is `8000`. In `retrofit` I set the  `BASE_URL ="http://192.168.56.1:8000/api/";` When I start the app and try to login, I get this error

```
D/OkHttp: --> POST http://192.168.56.1:8000/api/login/ http/1.1
D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 37
D/OkHttp: {"password":"mara","username":"mara"}
D/OkHttp: --> END POST (37-byte body)
D/TcpOptimizer: TcpOptimizer-ON
D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP FAILED: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to 
connect to /192.168.56.1 (port 8000) from /192.168.137.85 (port 38536) after 10000ms
```

Android seems to give me an random port every time I try to connect.
I use `API-level 28`. I do don't know how should I solve the problem, because just using the emulator cannot solve my problem.

Comment: When it comes to a problem of access I think about firewall, maybe you should  desactivate it

Comment: Thank you very much, you are right, it works if the firewall is deactivated.

Comment: I am glade I helped you